# Replication from multiple inheritance in Eiffel

Tags: polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, eiffel

I am struggling to understand the interplay of multiple inheritance with replication and polymorphism. Please consider the following classes forming a classical diamond pattern.

```
deferred class A
  feature 
    a  deferred end
  end

deferred class B
  inherit A
    rename a as b end
  end

deferred class C
  inherit A
    rename a as c end
end

class D
  inherit 
    B
    C
    select c end
feature
  b do print("b") end
  c do print("c") end
end
```

If I attach an instance of D to an object `ob_as_c` of type C, then `ob_as_c.c` prints "c" as expected. However, if attach the instance to an object `ob_as_b` of type B, then `ob_as_b.b` will print also print "c".

Is this intended behaviour? Obviously, I would like `ob_as_b.b` to print "b".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just describing the actual behavior in EiffelStudio which may differ from the actual ECMA specification.

What is happening is that without the **select** both *b* and *c* corresponds to a version of *a*. The compiler would complain that you have 2 routines with different name but same version. By using `select' you are fixing the error and telling the compiler that for dynamic binding the version to use is *c* and this is regardless of the type of the target, it is  based on the type of the target at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately, this makes Eiffel's inheritance features much less useful to me.

Comment: Regarding ECMA specification: Doesn't 8.16.11, "Definition: Dynamic binding version", state that in my example `ob_as_b.b` should print "b" since there is only an conformace path from D to B and feature b of D is the inherited feature b of B? The select clause should only be relevant when there are two or more conformance paths.

Answer (score 0):

(Cosmetics: the spelling is "deferred". Otherwise it won't compile!)

"select" only affects the semantics of a call whose target is an entity declared with the repeated ancestor type, here A, since in this case we need a disambiguation. For entities of type B, C or D there is no ambiguity, so the normal rules of polymorphism and dynamic binding apply: for the same target object, it does not matter whether the entity (the name in the program) is declared of type B or C.

-- Bertrand Meyer

Comment: What you describe is the behavior that I expected and that, I think, is specified in 8.16.11 in the ECMA standard. However, this is not what happens in EiffelStudio: In my example, the result of `ob_as_b.b` depends on the select clause in D, even though B is not a repeated ancestor of D.  (Btw, I fixed the embarassing typo.)